# hi I've just done engine overhaul car is not starting

Tags: engine, starting, fiat

Good day. I've just done an engine overhaul of a Fiat Palio 16. When I try to start it the is swing but not start.

Comment: What do you hear when you try to start the engine?

Comment: Tell us what parts of the engine you have changed/adjusted.

Comment: The very basic needs of your engine are spark, fuel, and pretty importantly air flow. Although it might at least kick over once if air flow is restricted. Have you tested for spark and proper fuel pressure / fuel in the carb bowl? (I have no idea if a Fiat Palio 16 is fuel injected or carburated,) How old is this car btw?

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange and thanks for your contribution.  You can click on this link and take the tour to see how the site works.  http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/tour   Thanks for contributing with your question.  We'll need some additional information to answer your question.  As much information you can add to your question will help us to answer it.  Again, welcome to SE.  Cheers!

Comment: By "is swing", do you mean the engine rotates freely when the starter is engaged?

Comment: What year is the car?

Comment: Down voted because your third sentence makes no sense. Please provide additional details.